# C# WPF Stackpanel showing child elements outside border

Tags: c#, wpf, overflow, stackpanel, margin

I have a parent stackpanel of fixed width 400 and a child stack panel with elements that make its width more than 400 (~1200)
I animate the inner stackpanels margin property to slide between views.
if I give the inner stackpanel a margin of -800+ it shows the entire inner stackpanel outside of the outer stack panel... if I make the margin -799 it hides it. I don't understand why this behavior is happening... 
my code is below

```
<s:ScatterViewItem
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:loc="http://schemas.tomer.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         loc:Translate.Uid="999" FlowDirection="{loc:Translate}"
         xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
         xmlns:customTreeView="clr-namespace:ADSIC.CustomControls.CustomTreeView"
         x:Class="ADSIC.View.ScatterViews.MapsView" 
         DataContext="{Binding}" Height="370" Style="{StaticResource ScatterViewItemStyle1}" Background="Transparent" CanRotate="False" CanMove="True" CanScale="False" Width="450"
                            Center="500,500" Visibility="Visible" >
<Grid Width="450" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" AllowDrop="False" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="DragBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource DragBorderBrush}" Background="#64000000"  Height="15" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0"  BorderThickness="1" Opacity="1"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="437" Margin="0 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" Margin="0 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="SlidingPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-799 0 0 0">
                <Border x:Name="MapServicesContainer" BorderBrush="{StaticResource WindowBrush}" Background="{StaticResource WindowBrush}" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3"  Height="320" Width="400" Visibility="Visible">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Direction="0" Opacity="0.5"  ShadowDepth="0"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Margin="15,12,12,12" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="24" loc:Translate.Uid="377" Text="{loc:Translate}" ></TextBlock>
                        <customTreeView:TreeViewControl x:Name="Tree" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,-12,0" Height="250" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>

                <Border x:Name="SavedMapsContainer" BorderBrush="{StaticResource WindowBrush}" Background="{StaticResource WindowBrush}" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3"  Height="320" Width="400" Visibility="Visible">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Direction="0" Opacity="0.5"  ShadowDepth="0"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Margin="12" Foreground="White" FontSize="24" loc:Translate.Uid="375" Text="{loc:Translate}" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="Segoe UI"></TextBlock>
                        <s:SurfaceListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SavedSessions, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Transparent" Height="250" Visibility="{Binding}" >
                            <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type s:SurfaceListBoxItem}" >
                                                <Grid x:Name="Border" Width="160" Background="Transparent">
                                                    <!--<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,10,0" />-->
                                                    <Grid x:Name="innerGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,0" >
                                                        <Grid.Background>
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                                <GradientStop Color="DimGray" Offset="0"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                        </Grid.Background>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Image Height="100" Width="130" Margin="5,10,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Foreground="White" Margin="10,112,10,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="28" />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                    <s:SurfaceButton x:Name="CloseButton" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,-8,-7,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding Path=RemoveSession}">
                                                        <s:SurfaceButton.Template>
                                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                                <Border CornerRadius="90" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Height="20" Width="20">
                                                                    <Border Height="20" Width="20" Background="White"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                                        <Border.OpacityMask>
                                                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources\Images\appbar.close.png"></ImageBrush>
                                                                        </Border.OpacityMask>
                                                                    </Border>
                                                                </Border>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </s:SurfaceButton.Template>
                                                    </s:SurfaceButton>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="CloseButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                        <Setter TargetName="innerGrid" Property="Background" Value="DimGray"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel Width="320"  ItemWidth="160" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></WrapPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>

                        </s:SurfaceListBox>
                        <TextBlock Margin="12" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" loc:Translate.Uid="269" Text="{loc:Translate}" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Visibility="{Binding}"></TextBlock>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <!-- Binded, Added remove item -->
                <Border x:Name="SaveMapContainer" BorderBrush="{StaticResource WindowBrush}" Background="{StaticResource WindowBrush}" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3"  Height="320" Width="400" 
                    Visibility="Visible">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Direction="0" Opacity="0.5"  ShadowDepth="0"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Margin="12" Foreground="White" FontSize="24" loc:Translate.Uid="90" Text="{loc:Translate}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="12,0" Foreground="White" loc:Translate.Uid="378" Text="{loc:Translate}"></TextBlock>
                        <s:SurfaceTextBox Text="{Binding Path=SessionTitle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="372" MaxLength="50" Padding="6,5,0,0" Style="{StaticResource NormalTextBoxStyle}" Margin="12,6,10,1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <s:SurfaceButton Style="{StaticResource SurfaceButtonStyleXBlack}" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5 0 0 0" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
            <s:SurfaceButton Style="{StaticResource SurfaceButtonStyleQuestionBlack}" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5 5 0 0" Command="{Binding HelpCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,-10,0,10">
        <s:SurfaceButton Style="{StaticResource BlackButtonWithImageStyle}" x:Name="ShowSavedMapsButton"  Height="32" Margin="0 10 10 0" 
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                         Visibility="Visible" Click="ShowSavedMapsButton_OnClick">
            <s:SurfaceButton.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0">
                    <Image Height="20" Source="/Resources\Images\SavedMaps.png"></Image>
                    <!-- put path to icon here -->
                    <TextBlock loc:Translate.Uid="379" Text="{loc:Translate}"  Foreground="White" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="15" Margin="3,-1,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </s:SurfaceButton.Content>
        </s:SurfaceButton>
        <s:SurfaceButton Style="{StaticResource BlackButtonWithImageStyle}" x:Name="ShowMapLayersButton"  Height="32" Margin="0 10 10 0" 
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                         Visibility="Visible" Click="ShowMapLayersButton_OnClick">
            <s:SurfaceButton.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0">
                    <Image Height="20" Source="/Resources\Images\ADSIC_ShowSavedMaps.png"></Image>
                    <!-- put path to icon here -->
                    <TextBlock loc:Translate.Uid="380" Text="{loc:Translate}"  Foreground="White" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="15" Margin="3,-1,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </s:SurfaceButton.Content>
        </s:SurfaceButton>
        <s:SurfaceButton Style="{StaticResource BlackButtonStyle}" x:Name="CancelButton" loc:Translate.Uid="3" Content="{loc:Translate}" Width="110" Height="32" Margin="0 10 10 0" Padding="0,-1,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="CancelButton_OnClick" Visibility="Collapsed">
        </s:SurfaceButton>
        <s:SurfaceButton Style="{StaticResource BlackButtonStyle}" x:Name="SaveButton" Content="{loc:Translate}" loc:Translate.Uid="10" Height="32" Margin="0 10 5 0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                         Padding="10,-1,10,0"
                         Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Visibility="Collapsed">
        </s:SurfaceButton>
        <s:SurfaceButton Style="{StaticResource BlackButtonWithImageStyle}" x:Name="SaveMapButton"  Height="32" Margin="0 10 10 0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="SaveMapButton_OnClick">
            <s:SurfaceButton.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0">
                    <Image Height="20" Source="/Resources\Images\ADSIC_Add_New_Bookmark.png"></Image>
                    <!-- put path to icon here -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{loc:Translate}" loc:Translate.Uid="90" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="15" Margin="3,-1,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </s:SurfaceButton.Content>

        </s:SurfaceButton>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```